# Proof of Theorem 3.4.12 in Emily Riehl's "Category Theory in Context"

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I have questions about the proof of Theorem 3.4.12 in Emily Riehl's *Category Theory in Context*.
The theorem states that the colimit of a small diagram $F\colon \mathsf J \to\mathsf C$ can be expressed as a coequalizer between two arrows $c,d\colon\coprod_{f\in\operatorname{mor} J}F(\operatorname{dom} f) \rightarrow \coprod_{j\in\operatorname{ob} J} Fj$:

The theorem: [image: 1] We assume that $\mathsf C$ is locally small.

In the first step of the proof, Riehl constructs this diagram: [image: 2]
The aim of the proof is to show that $C$ defines a colimit of $F.$
By using the fact that the contravariant Yoneda embedding $\mathsf C^{\operatorname{op}} \to \mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf C} $ preserves limits in $\mathsf C^{\operatorname{op}}$, we get the following equalizer diagram in $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf{C}}$: [image: 3]

My questions arise in the next steps. Since contravariant representable functors $\mathsf C(-,X)$ carry colimits in $\mathsf C$ to limits in $\mathsf{Set}$, Riehl claims that we get: [image: 4]

**The first thing I don't understand is how $\mathsf C(d,X)$ becomes $c$ and $\mathsf C(c,X)$ becomes $d$.**

The next step of the proof would be to fix $X$. Since the evaluation functor $\operatorname{ev}_X\colon \mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf C} \to \mathsf{Set}$ preserves limits, we have an equalizer diagram in $\mathsf{Set}$.

We use a special case ($\mathsf C= \mathsf{Set}$) of the theorem for limits on the diagram $\mathsf{C}(F-,X)\colon \mathsf J^{\operatorname{op}} \overset{F}{\rightarrow} \mathsf C^{\operatorname{op}} \overset{\mathsf C(-,X)}{\to} \mathsf{Set}$ to conclude that $\lim_{\mathsf{J}^{\operatorname{op}}} \mathsf{C}(F-,X)\cong\mathsf{C}(C,X)$ for each $X \in \mathsf C$. The theorem: [image: 5] **But how do we know that $c,d$ in (3.4.14) are those arrows whose equalizer is $\lim_{\mathsf{J}^{\operatorname{op}}} \mathsf{C}(F-,X)$?**

The end of the proof goes as follows: Let $\operatorname{ob} \mathsf C$ be the maximal discrete subcategory of $\mathsf C$. Since $\operatorname{ob} \mathsf C$ is discrete, the collection of the isomorphisms is an isomorphism in $\mathsf{Set}^{\operatorname{ob} \mathsf C}$. Then, I think, Riehl uses that the forgetful functor $\mathsf{Set}^{\mathsf C} \to \mathsf{Set}^{\operatorname{ob}\mathsf C}$ strictly creates all limits in $\mathsf{Set}$. In fact, she cites the proposition, but it actually needs $\mathsf C$ to be small:

> Proposition 3.3.9. *If $\mathsf A$ is small, then the forgetful functor $\mathsf C^{\mathsf A} \to \mathsf C^{\operatorname{ob}\mathsf A}$ strictly creates all limits and colimits that exist in $\mathsf C$. These limits are defined objectwise, meaning that for each $a\in \mathsf A$, the evaluation functor $\operatorname{ev}_a\colon \mathsf C^{\mathsf A}\to\mathsf C$ preserves all limits and colimits existing in $\mathsf C$.*

**Why can we use this proposition?**

The proposition gives us that $\mathsf C(C,-)$ is the limit of the $\mathsf J^{\operatorname{op}}$-indexed diagram of covariant functors $\mathsf C(Fj,-)$.
We conclude that $C$ is the colimit of $F$ since

> Theorem 3.4.7. *For any diagram $F\colon \mathsf J \to\mathsf C$ whose colimit exists, there is a natural isomorphism
> $$
> \mathsf{C}(\operatorname{colim}\nolimits_{\mathsf{J}} F,X)\cong \lim\nolimits_{\mathsf{J}^{\operatorname{op}}} \mathsf{C}(F-,X).
> $$*

I hope someone can help me by answering my questions in bold.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! This seems like a great question, especially for a first time asker, but you may want to either make the images be displayed by writing `![1]` for the image you named $1$ for example, or by writing the diagrams in MathJax as in [this Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16888/1104384) (though it seems there's not yet a feature for diagonal arrows?). I think for this question the former option is fine but that's just my opinion. Hope you have a great day/night.

Comment: A comment which may or may not be helpful, but worth saying. This result is quite intuitive, and it could be possible to miss the forest for the trees. In particular, colimit of a diagram is a (universal) collection of maps from the objects in your diagram to some X, satisfying a compatibility. So this is first a map from a coproduct over the objects, which satisfy the compatibility (the two maps c,d encode this). Doing the case of a push out explicitly basically spells out the whole idea. This problem is a (worthwhile) exercise in Maclane, so you really can do it yourself! Welcome to MSE!

Comment: @ChrisH I came up with a direct proof. Suppose e: F => X is a cone under F with legs e_j = e \iota_j. This is equivalent to e_j Ff = e_i for all f: i -> j, but we have e_j Ff = e c \iota_f and e_i = e d \iota_f. This is equivalent to ec = ed which implies a cone under F is exactly a cone under the coequalizer diagram. In particular, C is a colimit of F since it is for the coequalizer diagram. Does this work? I also now understand that c and d are given by the triangle above respectively by the square beneath in the ”correct way“. But I still have no clue why Riehl can use Proposition 3.3.9.

Comment: Great, seems like that works! Yea my best guess is that that proposition says colimits/limits in functor categories are computed point wise, and using it makes it easier(?) to show the functoriality of the construction. I might still be missing some motivation for why she proves it in this way, maybe it generalises better, but I feel if you're learning this stuff for the first time, having a clear intuitive understanding of your own proof is more important.